# Linear modeling of pseudobulk: how to model multiple types, conditions, and timepoints

Tags: mixed-model, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I have pseudobulk gene expression counts from multiple celltypes that I want to perform differential expression testing on. The study includes a treatment, a pre and post treatment timepoint, and multiple celltypes. The same individual is used for the two timepoints, so I also want to account for that.

See the metadata table in the following image. Note that this is a simplified version showing only one of the celltypes for each timepoint/condition combo. The `hash.ID` is the individual, which is re-factored as `ind.condition.ID` to be used in the model since the individuals are nested within condition. There is also a variable `capID` which represents the capture/batch. I want to account for batch effects if possible, but I was struggling to figure out a way to use the term without it being a linear combination of other terms (I tried doing a similar nested approach as the `ind.condition.ID` but was not successful).

[image]

The model I came up with initially was

```
~ celltype + condition:ind.condition.ID + condition * timepoint
```

But then I realized that I want celltype-specific effects of the condition and timepoints to be accounted for as well. So now I am considering something like

```
celltype + celltype:condition + celltype:timepoint + condition:ind.condition.ID + condition * timepoint
```

My main question is: what is the best way to model celltype, condition, and timepoint (and the interactions between those) while accounting for individual (and capture/batch if possible)?